# try to send AT commands from Arduino nano to ESP01

Tags: esp8266, arduino-nano, wifi

I encountered an issue when I try to send AT commands from Arduino nano to ESP01 I tried to find any tutorial for more helps, but I find nothing. please someone can help me.

I tried the tutorial from this link.
https://electronicslovers.com/2017/11/learn-how-to-setup-wifi-module-esp8266.html

But nothing happens when I type AT in serial monitor. I didn't see any response from the ESP module.

Comment: maybe the two modules are not connected together

Comment: Show your code. There are some errors in the code in the text of the linked article. For example,  here `if(a != ‘r’ && a != ‘n’ && (a < 32))` the 'n' should be '\n'  (new line character). Did you notice that the wiring diagram shows the top view of the ESP-01 module, not the underside which nomally you'd make the connections to.

Comment: I really connect them together as shown in the diagram on the site and I also already fixed the error in the code then I upload the code in the Arduino but always nothing.

Comment: I notice all you say 6v6gt but it's impossible communicate both microcontrollers.

Comment: this is my code.
`#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial softSerial(3, 2); // RX, TX
 
void setup() 
{
  uint32_t baud = 9600;
  Serial.begin(baud);
  softSerial.begin(baud);
  Serial.print("SETUP!! @");
  Serial.println(baud);
}
 
void loop() 
{
    while(softSerial.available() > 0) 
    {
      char a = softSerial.read();
      if(a == '\0')
        continue;
      if(a != '\r' && a != '\n' && (a < 32))
        continue;
      Serial.print(a);
    }`

Comment: the other part of the code here
`while(Serial.available() > 0)
    {
      char a = Serial.read();
      Serial.write(a);
      softSerial.write(a);
    }
}`

Comment: Please put the code in your original question as comments are unsuitable for long pieces of code and it is very difficult to read.
The code does not anyway appear to match the diagram in your linked article. RX of one device should be connected to TX of the other device. Try: `SoftwareSerial softSerial(2, 3); // RX, TX note 2&3 intercahnged` .